# Simple Form Not Working in jQuery Overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to setup a pop up on my site which will allows users to subscribe to my email list, the form works fine when it is in the page (not within the popup). But as soon as I place it into my jQuery overlay (which appears after X seconds) the form doesn't work.

HTML

```
    <div class="main-content">
<p>Please <a class="show-popup" href="#">click here</a> to see the popup</p>
</div>

<div class="overlay-bg">
<div class="overlay-content">
<form action="http://wrd.createsend.com/t/y/s/qljjjl/" method="post" class="basic-grey" id="subform">
    <h1>Subscribe 
        <span>Sign up for our FREE monthly newsletter to stay up to date with the latest digital news, views and articles</span>
    </h1>
    <label for="fieldName">
        <span>Your Name:</span>
        <input id="fieldName" type="text" name="cm-name" placeholder="Your Full Name" />
    </label>
    <label for="fieldEmail">
        <span>Your Email:</span>
        <input id="fieldEmail" type="email" name="cm-qljjjl-qljjjl" placeholder="Valid Email Address" />
    </label>  
     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <button type="submit" class="button" form="subform">Subscribe</button>
    </label>    
</form>


</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// show popup when you click on the link
$('.show-popup').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault(); // disable normal link function so that it doesn't refresh the page
$('.overlay-bg').show(); //display your popup
});

// hide popup when user clicks on close button
$('.close-btn').click(function(){
$('.overlay-bg').hide(); // hide the overlay
});

// hides the popup if user clicks anywhere outside the container
$('.overlay-bg').click(function(){
    $('.overlay-bg').hide();
})
// prevents the overlay from closing if user clicks inside the popup overlay
$('.overlay-content').click(function(){
    return false;
});

});
</script>

        <script type="text/javascript">                                         
        $(document).ready(function() {

        function showpanel() { 
            if( $.cookie('showOnlyOne') ){
                //it is still within the day
                //hide the div
                $('#shownOnlyOnceADay').hide();
            } else {
                //either cookie already expired, or user never visit the site
                //create the cookie
                $.cookie('showOnlyOne', 'showOnlyOne', { expires: 10 });

                //and display the div
                $('.overlay-bg').fadeIn('slow'); // this will fade in the popup
}}

 setTimeout(showpanel, 3000)
        });
        </script>
```

As you can tell from the code above, I am also planning on showing the popup when somebody clicks a link.

You can checkout a demo of it (not working) here - if you wait 5 seconds the popup will show:

http://thiswebguy.com/testing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working also by adding:

```
 $('.button').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: Where did you add this?

Comment: If you add this just after where you disable the original click event it should work

Comment: try at line 30, and I could test it on your server

Answer (score 0):

the line

```
$('.overlay-content').click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

is stopping the form from registering the submit click.

change the function so that it either excludes the submit button

```
$('.overlay-content :not(:submit)').click(etc...)
```

or use the `event.srcElement` to return true

```
 $('.overlay-content').click(function(e){
if($(e.srcElement).is(':submit'))
        return true;
else return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately I tried using both solutions and the form still isn't working :(

Comment: Yes its because the :not(:submit) is getting overridden by the label. if you go with the answer above it will help i have added a comment to it